# Creating a dynamic grid layout depending on the resolution and dpi

Tags: android, android-layout

Indoor mapping Layout Example

[image]

How to create grid like this layout?
I tried using

```
<Scrollable FrameLayout>
 <Relative layout>
 <Gridview/>
 </Relative layout>
</Scrollable FrameLayout>
```

but the grid not really fill the entire screen

and I'm trying to use table layout
and looping tablerow depend on screen resolution

example width res: 1024/24(is my dimen) = 42
so im looping 42times to create 42 row but its too heavy even with asyntask

Answer (score 0):

try to use recyclerview with grid layout manager